# Select over a subquery having WITH clause

Tags: db2, subquery, db2-luw

I'm not familiar to DB2 and in Oracle we can do the following

```
select * from 
(WITH A AS (SELECT 'test' FROM DUAL)
 SELECT *
  FROM A )
```

I have a requirement to so similar to this in DB2, but it wont allow me. My requirement is not exactly same as above, but i simplified.

There is another issue, I'm trying to do a XML output on a results got using my below query. But the issue is when I call the `XMLFOREST` function, it restricts me to have only a column as input (in the example below example, `A*B` it does not allow).

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT (
      NAME "DATA",
      XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (NAME "DJ_STOCK", (XMLFOREST (A, B, A * B)))))
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT RTRIM (RTRIM (6.0000), '.') A,
                   RTRIM (RTRIM (6.0000), '.') B
              FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1))
```

I could do `A*B` in the inner query and call it as `C` and then call from the `xmlforest` function, but my actual scenario does not allow me to do that due to performance. Any workaround?

I'm using DB2 9.5 version

Comment: Use `XMLCONCAT` to assemble multiple XML elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole purpose of the common table expression (what you call the `WITH` clause) is to avoid subqueries, mostly for readability. Subsequently, the CTE is used in the outermost `SELECT`:

```
WITH A (B) AS (SELECT 'test' FROM DUAL)
select * from 
(SELECT *
  FROM A )
```

Note that you must provide names for calculated columns (`B` for the literal value `'test'` in the example above).

Comment: There is no DUAL table in DB2, equivalent it SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1.

Comment: @HarinathArasu -- there is, if Oracle compatibility is enabled, which would be a sensible thing to do for someone more familiar with Oracle, like the OP. Besides, nothing can prevent you from creating such a table yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with the XMLFOREST query, unless concatenating the data is an option, altough you can probably check the IBM page.[IBM XMLFOREST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_xmlforest.html)

The first query you are trying to make can be like this:

```
SELECT test
FROM ( SELECT 'test' AS test
       FROM DUAL) A
```

Although, i dont understand why you would want to do that instead of just calling the table, since you are not doing anything with the data.

Hope it helps.